# Creating a list of sentences from a file and adding it into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, spacy

I am using the code below to create a list of sentences from a file document. The function will return a list of sentences.

```
def extract_sentences(file):
    content = nlp(file)
    sentences = list(content.sents)
    return sentences
```

After that, I want to add each sentence in a dataframe, under the column "sentence". The problem is that in the dataframe, the sentences appear like a list of words, divided by comma, eg: (this, process, includes, different, stages...  ). But I want it to appear like: this process includes different stages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content.sents` is a generator object that holds `spacy.tokens.span.Span` objects.

If you want to have a list of strings as output, you can use

```py
def extract_sentences(file):
    content = nlp(file)
    return [x.text for x in content.sents]
```

Note the `.text` property returns the textual representation of the span object.

Answer (score 1):

`sentences` is a list per your function.
You may want to change your return statement to return a string instead.
The full function would therefore look like:

```
def extract_sentences(file):
    content = nlp(file)
    sentences = list(content.sents)
    return " ".join(x.text for x in sentences)
```